# How to print checkmark openhtmltopdf java

Tags: java, openhtmltopdf

Does anybody know how to print checkmark symbols like: ✓ `"&#10003;" "&#x2713;" "&check;"` ?
I have tried include some google fonts, in browser i see symbol, but after render - only # instead of ✓.

Answer (score 2):

> By default XML allows the use of five character entities being `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt`; and `&gt`;. If you'd like to use other character entities derived from XHTML such as `&nbsp`; then you can use the special project doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//OPENHTMLTOPDF//DOC XHTML Character Entities Only 1.0//EN" "">
```

You can check their [documentation](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/Integration-Guide#character-entities) about that.